# My Android App Keeps Crashing

Tags: android, crash

I've started to learn Android Development and I got this snippit off of google android development site, it keeps on crashing.

My specs are:

Android 4.0.3
API 15

Code:

```
package lewes.android.hello;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

I get...

Unfortenualy, HelloAndroid is not responding.

Please help me!

MY MANIFEST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lewes.android.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:name=".HelloWorld"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
03-17 11:35:19.835: D/AndroidRuntime(562): Shutting down VM
03-17 11:35:19.835: W/dalvikvm(562): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught 
exception (group=0x409c01f8) 
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to 
instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{lewes.android.hello/lewes.android.hello.HelloWorld}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lewes.android.hello.HelloWorld
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native 
Method)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562): Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lewes.android.hello.HelloWorld
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at  
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
03-17 11:35:19.914: E/AndroidRuntime(562):  ... 11 more
03-17 11:40:20.114: I/Process(562): Sending signal. PID: 562 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please help me!... No... Please send us your logcat: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Comment: Please show your logcat error

Comment: Window > Show View > Other
Then expand Android and then select LogCat

Comment: But it doesnt record, it contanstly changes.

Comment: It seems you should use your activity (`this`) after `onCreate()`. There is a [hello world](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) which uses static xml layout, I think you should begin with it.

Comment: Whats the name of your class under src?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete one of the application sections from your manifest.
Keep the one where the activity corresponds to the name of your class.

make your manifest look exactly like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lewes.android.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
android:name=".HelloAndroid"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: In the package explorer toolbar which is probably on the left side of your screen find androidmanifest.xml

Comment: click on it. then at the bottom of what comes up should say "manifest" "application" "permissions" "instrumentation" "AndroidManifest.xml" Click on the last one

Comment: are you using eclipse with the plugin?

Comment: I found it, Now should I add it?

Comment: I've fixed it, its now booting android.

Comment: Just copy what i have in my answer. and delete everything in your manifest. Then paste mine in.

Comment: Ok, I just did that, im retrying my boot.

Comment: Post your logcat again. It should be different now

Comment: I posted it! I think it has changed.

Comment: Whats the name of your activity under the src folder? is it HelloWorld.java?

Comment: You've still called it "HelloWorld" in the manifest - it should be "HelloAndroid" - how many times do you need telling?

Comment: @mpeerman - it will work now that you've changed it to "HelloAndroid" from the "HelloWorld" that you did have originally

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 <activity
        android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name=".HelloAndroid"
```

Comment: As your manifest stands you have two applications in it, both are MAIN and LAUNCHER. You just want one, make it have name as above, not "HelloAndroidActivity" or "HelloWorld" it must match the name of the class

Comment: Using the manifest in my answer should work. I have recreated this exactly how you have it and it works. I need the logcat to figure out why it isnt working for you after these changes

Answer (score 0):

SDK does not mention about this. But as my experience, activity (`this`) can not be used inside [`onCreate(Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) to ***initialize*** new objects. To be used as a parameter for constructors, `this` is nothing within `onCreate()`.

You can follow this [hello world](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html). It uses static xml layout.

Hope this helps you  :-)

Comment: yes it can be used. I have already copied his code and it ran perfect for me on an actual device. It seems he is using the emulator

Comment: Shall I try on my tablet then?

Comment: No lets just take this one step at a time.

Comment: @mpeerman, Thank you, I haven't tested before posting the answer. But if it works on real device, it will work on emulator properly. Hope you will find out the bug  :-)