# java - Android app crashes when button is pressed

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to get a part of a simple Android app working. I am confused as to why I am getting the error "Unfortunately, this app has stopped working".

Basically, I need the total value to increase when I click on a button based on what value they have. For example coffee adds 2 to the total. Every time I click a button that adds to the total value, the app crashes.

Here is the source code. I have just copied the parts that are specific to this problem.

```
package com.example.pp.application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    TextView tv01;
    Double Total = 0.00;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv01);

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    public void addCoffee() {

        Total = Total + 2.20;
        tv01.setText(""+Total+"");
    }

    public void addBus() {

        Total = Total + 1.90;
        tv01.setText(""+Total+"");
    }

    public void addMilk() {

        Total = Total + 1.50;
        tv01.setText(""+Total+"");

    }


}
```

And here is the Manifest:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/label">

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Coffee"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="addCoffee"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Bus"
    android:onClick="addBus"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Milk"
    android:onClick="addMilk"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/button5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="------------------"
    android:id="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Total"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tv01"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tv01" />
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv01);
    public void addCoffee(View v) {

    Total = Total + 2.20;
    tv01.setText(""+Total+"");
   }
   }
```

and continue with another function with same way

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `public void addCoffee()` your onClick method definition should look like `public void addCoffee(View v)`, where `v` is the widget you clicked on (in this case the `Button`). Take the same approach when updating other onClick methods. This requirement applies only to callbacks defined via `android:onClick` attribute in XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't posted the stack trace of the LogCat, I have no way of telling when in the code your error has been.

But it's likely to have occured before. These links contain similar stances and documentations about exceptions.

[My Android App Keeps Crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749315/my-android-app-keeps-crashing)

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/exceptions

https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/optimizing-your-app.html

[Android App Crashes on Button Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994457/android-app-crashes-on-button-click)